# Automatically resolve which implementation to use when deserializing using objectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am using objectMapper to deserialize xml to my object.

My xml has a section that has several possible fields, so I modeled my object using a sealed interface:

```java
public record Root(String id, Child child) {
    public sealed interface Child permits ChildA, ChildB, ChildC {
        String name();

        public record ChildA(String name, int a) implements Child {}
        public record ChildB(String name, int a, int b) implements Child {}
        public record ChildC(String name, int c) implements Child {}
    }
}
```

I want the objectMapper to automatically try to resolve the implementation

Currently I solved the issue by using JsonCreator to manually resolve the implementation:

```java
@JsonCreaor
static Root.Child creator(@JsonPopety("name") string name, 
                          @JsonPopety("a") Integer a, 
                          @JsonPopety("b") Integer b, 
                          @JsonPopety("c") Integer c) {
    if (a == null && b == null && c != null) return new Root.ChildC(name, c);
    if (a != null && b != null && c == null) return new Root.ChildB(name, a, b);
    if (a != null && b == null && c == null) return new Root.ChildA(name, a);
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

But this kind of manually resolution is pretty ugly, and because there are no abiguities I would hope that the mapper will be able to do it by itself, especially when I have several places like this.

The definition of my mapper is:

```java
XmlMapper.builder()
    .addModule(/*custom module for Instant class deserializer*/)
    .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSATIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
    .build()
    .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: You basically want to encode the same information you have in your static factory method in jackson annotations (if that is even possible). I don't think that this will be as concise as you got it currently. I would recommend sticking with your current solution.

Comment: It looks like one class with `Optional` properties not like 3 different types. I would create one type with all possible properties and used it to deserialise `XML` payload. Later you can decide which object to create based on the fields. There is no point to hide business logic inside deserialisation process. It would be hard to maintain in case number of properties increases or changes.

Comment: @MichałZiober It is not optional properties because having all of them non null (or a lot of other combinations) is an illegal state. Deciding what object it should be deserialized into is not business logic, it is data modeling, which should be hidden from the business logic and with the introduction of sealed interfaces + record pattern matching it is true now more than ever